# Self join within the table in mariaDB

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

In mongo we will use lookup to find datas using foreign key. Here in mariaDB how to use join to fetch the record from the same table. In my code i'm using node to run the backed and sequlize to connect mariaDB

Example:
In a table called category there is relation between id and parentId. how to put join within the same table.

```
SELECT * FROM categories child WHERE id = 9 
left join 'categories' parent ON 
child.parentId = parent.id
```

Solution:

```
SELECT * FROM `categories` child 
INNER JOIN `categories` parent ON
child.parentId = parent.id 
WHERE child.id = 9
```

Comment: What have you tried? Any **code** example?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `categories` child
WHERE id = 9
left join 'categories' parent
ON child.parentId = parent.id

Comment: Please look User manual about correct syntax - you cannot change clauses order in the query text, WHERE must be placed strictly after FROM ( including JOIN/ON) clause, not in the middle of it.

Comment: I second what @Akina said. Also, if you want to add more details please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65803933/edit) and add it there instead of posting as comment. While you're at it, you might as well add your expected result out of what you're trying to do. That would help to clarify some things.